# Can someone help to find / create / add a device in Eagle Library?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, library, device

I want to use FSL176MRT a  integrated Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) controller and SenseFET IC in my SMPS's PCB design in **EAGLE**.

It is not available in any library.
Its a 6 lead TO-220 package device

I've tried but it has different pin structure than normal IC's

Any help is very much appreciated..thanks :)

[image]

Comment: "NO PACKAGE STANDARD APPLIES" "It is not available in any library." Yes, that's what that means.

Comment: The fastest and most reliable way is to make it yourself. That way, you can be sure that the footprint is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know already, invest some time in [understanding the various layers](https://learn.adafruit.com/ktowns-ultimate-creating-parts-in-eagle-tutorial/creating-a-package-outline) and [learning how to create your own part](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/110).

Making a part has two steps - 1) Making the symbol and 2) Making the package

Symbol is what you use while making schematics. It should contain all the pins that you have in your part. For you part:

[image: FET]

The symbol will be a rectangular box containing six pins labelled as the pins in above diagrams. You can decide the placement which helps you while making schematic. For ex - Giving GND pins on the lower part, VCC on top or top left, inputs on left, outputs on right etc.

Once the symbol is done, you need to make package. Package is what you actually see on the board. It has some pads (smd or through hole) and some silk (diagram + text) to help you figure out the orientation and boundary of the component. You need to be extra careful about pads - both placement and drill size (in case of through hole) otherwise component will not go comfortably on the designed pad. All the info is already available in the datasheet. The image that you have posted is enough for making a package.

Once you have made your symbol and package, you need to combine them (which pin connects to what pad).

Once done, it's a good practice to take a print out of the new designed package in 1:1 ratio and compare with the original component whether it's correct or not.

Comment: I'm new to eagle...I'll follow the links that u've given... thanks!!